# Snort fails when run as a service

Tags: ids, snort

I've got Snort compiled, configured, and running. Only problem I have is that it fails when I try to run it as a service. I've mainly been using the guide from here: https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/012/147/original/Snort_3.1.8.0_on_Ubuntu_18_and_20.pdf.

Running

```
snort -u snort -g snort -c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort/snort.lua -s 65535 -k none -l /var/log/snort -i enp3s0:enp4s0 -m 0x1b --plugin-path=/usr/local/etc/so_rules
```

from the terminal has no issue except that when try to stop it, it says that it's stopping but never stops. I have to send a SIGKILL to kill it.

Service file:

```
[Unit]  
Description=Snort3 NIDS Daemon  
After=syslog.target network.target  

[Service]  
Type=simple  
ExecStart=/usr/local/snort/bin/snort -Q -q -u snort -g snort -c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort/snort.lua snort -s 65535
-k none -l /var/log/snort -D -i enp3s0:enp4s0 -m 0xlb --create-pidfile
--plugin-path=/usr/local/etc/so_rules/

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Output of 'systemctl status snort3':

```
root@snort:~# systemctl status snort3  
× snort3.service - Snort3 NIDS Daemon  
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snort3.service; enabled; preset: enabled)  
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-01-02 13:18:44 CST; 6min ago  
Duration: 64ms  
Process: 798 ExecStart=/usr/local/snort/bin/snort -Q -q -u snort -g snort -c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort/snort.lua s>  
Main PID: 798 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  
CPU: 57ms  

Jan 02 13:18:44 snort systemd[1]: Started snort3.service - Snort3 NIDS Daemon.  
Jan 02 13:18:44 snort snort[798]: ERROR: unknown option - snort  
Jan 02 13:18:44 snort snort[798]: ERROR: can't set -m 0xlb  
Jan 02 13:18:44 snort snort[798]: ERROR: usage: -m set the process file mode creation mask  
Jan 02 13:18:44 snort snort[798]: FATAL: see prior 3 errors  
Jan 02 13:18:44 snort snort[798]: Fatal Error, Quitting..  
Jan 02 13:18:44 snort systemd[1]: snort3.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE  
Jan 02 13:18:44 snort systemd[1]: snort3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Snort version:

```
,,_ -> Snort++ <-  
o" )~ Version 3.1.76.0  
'''' By Martin Roesch & The Snort Team  
http://snort.org/contact#team  
Copyright (C) 2014-2023 Cisco and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.  
Copyright (C) 1998-2013 Sourcefire, Inc., et al.  
Using DAQ version 3.0.13  
Using LuaJIT version 2.1.0-beta3  
Using OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023  
Using libpcap version 1.10.3 (with TPACKET_V3)  
Using PCRE version 8.39 2016-06-14  
Using ZLIB version 1.2.13  
Using Hyperscan version 5.4.2 2023-12-25  
Using LZMA version 5.4.1
```

OS: Debian 12

Comment: And you checked the option that it threw an error about?

Comment: It looks like the author of that guide has a lot of problems with `-m` https://seclists.org/snort/2019/q1/22 I'd look at other examples that treat `-m` differently (or omit it)

Comment: Certainly, and it works with no issue when run from the terminal.

Comment: Did you run it in term with high verbosity? There might be an underlying problem